# How to find an extension of the file when I download it from AWS Glacier?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-glacier

I have a lot of video files archived in the AWS Glacier. Majority of them have ".mp4" format, How can I get an extension of a file stored in the archive?

I use php-aws-sdk and Laravel. I'm trying to remove that hardcoded ".mp4", It returns me a "stream" when I'm trying to get "$result->get('body')", I didn't see any fields with extension of the file in that object.

```
    $result = $this->client->getJobOutput([
        'accountId' => config('aws.account_id'),
        'jobId' => $job_id,
        'vaultName' => config('aws.vault_name'),
    ]);

    $video_file_name = '/tmp/' . $archive_name . '.mp4'; 

    $video_file_path = public_path($video_file_name);
    $fp = fopen($video_file_path, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $video_source_stream);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You can't, unless you stored it yourself somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is opposite, I mean how to get an extension when I'm going to download a  file from glacier, I don't have that file on my server yet.

What glacier returns me is:

GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream^ {#1155
-stream: stream resource {@722
wrapper_type: "PHP"
stream_type: "TEMP"
mode: "w+b"
unread_bytes: 0
seekable: true
uri: "php://temp"
options: []
}
-size: null
-seekable: true
-readable: true
-writable: true
-uri: "php://temp"
-customMetadata: []
}

I can use ->get('body') of that stream object and save it to the file. But how to find our what is the extension there, of a file I'm going to create?

```
$fp = fopen('/tmp/' . $archive_name . '.mp4', "w");
fwrite($fp, $result->get('body'));
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$extension = pathinfo(storage_path('/uploads/my_image.jpg'), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);dd($extension);
//Where $file is an instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadFile
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```